# Is there a way to tell Swagger UI to cache prior field values so we're not constantly having to retype them?

Tags: caching, swagger-ui

We're using Swagger UI on top of a Lambda app. Everything works fine as expected.

But wondering if there's a way to tell the UI to cache prior used values so that when I bring the UI up again later, I can just click on the field and select? Like most websites do.